# How to find the largest possible minimum eigenvalue for a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an arbitrary set and let $\phi: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\lVert \phi(x)\rVert_2 \leq 1, \ \forall x \in \mathcal{X}$. Suppose $x$ is drawn from $\mathcal{X}$ according to $P$ and define a matrix $A$ as $$A = \underset{{x \sim P}}{\mathbb{E}}\left[ \, \,\phi(x) \phi(x)^\top \right]$$ I watched a [talk](https://youtu.be/3QIFA2WQYFs?t=842) in which it was said that the largest possible minimum eigenvalue is $\frac1d$.  Can anybody help me to figure out why the following holds?

$$\max_{P \in \Delta(\mathcal{X})} \sigma_{\min}(A) = \frac{1}{d}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see this is to note that the sum of the eigenvalues $\sigma_1 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_d$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
\sigma_1 + \cdots + \sigma_d  &= \operatorname{tr}\Bbb E[\phi(x)\phi(x)^\top] = \Bbb E(\operatorname{tr}[\phi(x)\phi(x)^\top]) 
\\ & = \Bbb E[\phi(x)^\top\phi(x)] = \Bbb E(\|\phi(x)\|^2) \leq 1.
\end{align}
Thus, we have
$$
1 \geq \sigma_1 + \cdots + \sigma_d \geq \sigma_d + \cdots + \sigma_d = d\sigma_d.
$$
That is, $1 \geq d \sigma_d \implies \sigma_d \leq \frac 1d$.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and complete proof!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What's the trace of $\phi(x)\phi(x)^T$. With the assumption given, you can bound it by $1$. The trace of a diagonalizable matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues. You can show that the sum of the eigenvalues is less than or equal to 1. You have d eigenvalues whose sum is less than or equal to 1. Can the smallest be strictly bigger than $1/d$?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I haven't considered the trace idea! I think Ben gives complete proof of your idea :-)